# How to calculate reverb parameters for virtual environment?

Tags: audio, game-engine, game-development, fmod

Currently, I'm working on custom game engine and we need to implement something similar to Steam Audio features using FMOD Studio. We tried Steam Audio and Resonance Audio. For several reasons we unable to use them in our project. So we need to figure out how to implement these features with built-in FMOD tools, at least using custom DSPs.

The questions is how calculate reverb parameters?

Assuming, I have grid of reverb-probes and able to trace and sample all neighboring material properties.
Sabine equation allows to calculate T60 for different frequencies according to absorption coefficient for these materials. But how to calculate Late and Early delay, Diffusion, Density, High cut, Low gain etc?

Thank you in advance!